# How to iterate through 2 different types of queues at the same? Java

Tags: java, iterator, queue

I have 2 queues right now. One holds a queue of Strings and the other holds a queue of integers. I was wondering of there is a way to iterate through the both of them at the same time.

For example:

Let's say the integer queue has: 1, 2, 3 and the string one has: North, East, West

I want to print out:

1 mile(s) North

2 mile(s) East

3 mile(s) West

and I want this to go until the queue runs out. I plan on having something like maybe a text file that gives the information so I do not know how much is in each queue. Thanks.

```
Iterator<Double> it = myNumbers.iterator();
  while(it.hasNext())
  {
     temp = myNumbers.remove();
     System.out.println(temp + " miles");
     myNum.add(temp);
  }
```

Comment: How do you plan to iterate over 1 queue?

Comment: I've added the code for the single queue that I've done

Comment: Are both queues always the same size?

Comment: What do you mean by the same?

Comment: As in, for every string (north, east, etc.) there will be an integer?

Comment: Yes, there should be an integer for every string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If q1 and q2 have different size, and you need to print the extra elements as well, just add another code block to iterate through the rest of the elements on the iterator whose `hasNext()` returns true.

```
Queue<String> q1 = new LinkedList<>();
Queue<Integer> q2 = new LinkedList<>();

q1.add("North");
q1.add("East");
q1.add("West");
q2.add(1);
q2.add(2);
q2.add(3);

Iterator<String> i1 = q1.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> i2 = q2.iterator();

while (i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(i2.next() + " Mile(s) " + i1.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If both have always same size, just pull from both in the same loop run. If different sizes use a for-loop that counts up to the smaller size, or the bigger size and always check hasNext().

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
Iterator<Integer> miles // your integers iterator
Iterator<String> directions // your strings iterator
while (miles.hasNext() && directions.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(miles.next() + " mile(s) " + directions.next());
}
```

But, I would say this approach with two iterators is fragile. Would be better if you create a class which contains miles and direction and then have only one iterator with an objects of this class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both queues are always the same size, why not take from both at the same time? You could also make an object holding both values and put it into one queue.

```
// Iterate through both at the same time if they are the same size.
while(queue1.hasNext() && queue2.hasNext()) {
    // remove and print
}

// Or create a class
class Move {
    public int miles;
    public String direction;
    public Move(String d, int m) {
        miles = m;
        direction = d;
    }
    void toString() {
        return miles+" Mile(s)" + direction;
    }
}

Queue<Move> moveQueue = new LinkedList<>();
Iterator<Move> it = moveQueue.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next().toString());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can convert your Queues to arrays, with `toArray()` method.
And then just use a loop.